# Django: Handling several forms in one submit, using class based views?

Tags: python, django, forms, inheritance

I am using django 1.6 and I have a Product model which I am making an edit-page for where you can edit all aspects of a product. Since a product has quite a few properties, some represented by other models (ProductText, ProductPrice, ExtraImage, etc), I have different model forms on the python end represending these things, and in the template I want to render all those forms within the same  tag, creating one big form to post them all.

However, since all class based views provided with django seems to deal with only one form instance, what is my best bet to handle all of them?

I understand that I have to inherit somewhere in the inheritance tree, but looking in the django source, the view inheritance is somewhat complex with mixins and whatnot so I don't really know what would be smartest to inherit in my case to avoid reinventing too many wheels.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: below I've put skeleton, which can be extended for so many forms as you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Urls**:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<model1_pk>\d+)/(?P<model2_pk>\d+)/$', EditBaseForm.as_view(), name='edit'),
```

**View**:

```
class EditBaseForm(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'some_edit.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object1 = get_object_or_404(SomeModel1, pk=kwargs.get('model1_pk'))
        self.object2 = get_object_or_404(SomeModel2, pk=kwargs.get('model2_pk'))
        # and so on

        return super(EditBaseForm, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditBaseForm, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if not (context.get('form1') and context.get('form2')):  # actually you can check only first of them
            context['form1'] = FormClass1(instance=self.object1)
            context['form2'] = FormClass2(instance=self.object2)

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form1 = FormClass1(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=self.object1)
        form2 = FormClass2(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=self.object2)

        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form1, form2)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form1, form2)

    def form_valid(self, form1, form2):
        form1.save()
        form2.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form1, form2):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form1=form1,
                form2=form2,
            )
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('some_app:some_url')
```

**Template**:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1.as_p }}
    {{ form2.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Flawless answer and worked perfectly except that in the dispatch method, I needed "self." before the object1, object2 variable names.